# Rename attribute in a JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Hello here is my json

```
{
 "name":'test',
 "options": {
    "Repartition": "Active",
    "Satellite": "No"
  }
}
```

I'd like to rename "Satellite" in "Satellites" with an 's' but I don't managed to.

I tried :

```
UPDATE "Liaison" set content = content->>'options' - 'Satellite' || jsonb_build_object('Satellites', content->>'options'->'Satellite') where id =52056
```

But I have an error :

> operator is not unique: unknown - unknown

Here is my table :

```
    ID   |  content
  ---------------------
   52056 |  the json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->>` returns the element as `text`, so you lose the ability to apply JSON operators on it. You need to use `->` to return the (sub) element as JSON and use `jsonb_set()` to change the `options` element in the content:

```
UPDATE "Liaison" 
   set content = jsonb_set(content, array['options'], 
                           (content -> 'options') - 'Satellite'||
                           jsonb_build_object('Satellites', content -> 'options' -> 'Satellite'))
where id = 52056;
```

The `-` operator however only works for JSONB, not JSON. So if your columns is indeed JSON, you need to cast the intermediate result to JSONB.

Online example: http://rextester.com/EXTS36112

---

Another option is to use `jsonb_set()` to create a new element and `#-` to remove the old.

```
UPDATE liaison 
   set content = jsonb_set(
                    content, 
                    array['options','Satellites'], 
                    (content #> array['options','Satellite']), true
                 ) #- array['options','Satellite']
where id = 52056;
```

Comment: Thanks the problem now is the entire content is replaced by 'options' object