# How to rename a key in a jsonb list?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to rename a json key of all the objects in a list e.g. given `my_table` with `my_col` containing a jsonb list:

```
[{name:0}, {name:1}, {name:2}]
```

I have worked out how to change a single element of a list by removing and adding a key using explicit indexing e.g.

```
select (my_col->0)::jsonb - 'name' || 
        jsonb_build_object('new_name', my_col->0->'name') 
from my_table
```

But how can this then be applied to all elements in the list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621409

Comment: the tricky part is changing data inside a list - I can't see any jsonb operators that iterate across lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my best answer so far that works using a lateral join.

```
update my_table t1
set my_col = 
    (select json_agg(el::jsonb - 'name' || jsonb_build_object('new_name', el->'name')) 
     from my_table t2, jsonb_array_elements(t2.my_col) as el 
     where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Ideally there would just be some neat pattern matching operators e.g. `my_col->*->'name'`.