# How to change the name of a key in a JSON object stored in Postgres for all records

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table called `priceTables` I am storing in a column named `value` a JSON object that looks something similar to this:

```json
{
  "price": {
    "values": {
       "tax": 1.59
     }
  }
}
```

And would like to run a query to migrate tens of thousands of records to change the name of `values` to `breakdown`. So it will result in

```json
{
  "price": {
    "breakdown": {
      "tax": 1.59
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on the Postgres query for achieving this?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48621595/9778755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
UPDATE priceTables
SET value = value || jsonb_build_object(
  'price',
  jsonb_build_object(
    'breakdown',
    priceTables.value #> '{price,values}'
  )
)
WHERE priceTables.value #> '{price,values}' IS NOT NULL;
```

Generic version to rename second-level key in a JSONB column:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET json_column = json_column || jsonb_build_object(
  'level_1_key',
  jsonb_build_object(
    'level_2_key_renamed',
    json_col #> '{level_1_key,level_2_key}'
  )
)
WHERE my_table.json_col #> '{level_1_key,level_2_key}' IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 8):

If the name can only occur once in the JSON or if all occurrences should be replaced if there are more, a quick and dirty one is a simple `replace()` in the text:

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET value = replace(value::text, '"values"', '"breakdown"')::jsonb;
```

(Replace `jsonb` with `json` if the type of the column is `json` rather than `jsonb`.)

Comment: would not recommend this.